# Showing that a sequence is Cauchy w.r.t. $d(x, y) = \left|e^{x} - e^{y}\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to demonstrate that a metric space $X$ is not complete with the metric $d(x, y) = \left|e^x - e^y\right|$. To this end I am first trying to show that a sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is Cauchy w.r.t. the said metric. My current mental block is with the "final touch", where one shows that the distance between any two elements of the sequence is at most $\epsilon$. Specifically, let $n_\epsilon > \left|\frac{1}{\ln(\epsilon)}\right|$. Then, for $l, k \geq n_\epsilon$ it holds that $\left|e^{x_l} - e^{x_k}\right| = \left|e^{\frac{1}{l}} - e^{\frac{1}{k}}\right| < \left|e^{\frac{1}{\min\{l, k\}}}\right| \leq \left|e^{\frac{1}{n_\epsilon}}\right| < \left|e^{\left|\ln(\epsilon)\right|}\right|$.

This might seem as an elementary step to most, but how to you go about with the absolute value around the logarithm in the exponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work since $e^{1/n} > e^0 = 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and  we can find no bound $e^{1/n_\epsilon} < \epsilon <1$.

Instead, for $l > k > n$, we have

$$\left|e^{\frac{1}{l}} - e^{\frac{1}{k}} \right|= e^{\frac{1}{k}}(1 - e^{\frac{1}{l}- \frac{1}{k}}) \leqslant e \cdot \left(1 - e^{-\left(\frac{1}{k}- \frac{1}{l}\right)} \right)$$

Since $e^{-x} \geqslant 1 - x $ for $0 \leqslant x < 1$, it follows that with $n > 1/(e\epsilon)$,

$$\left|e^{\frac{1}{l}} - e^{\frac{1}{k}} \right|\leqslant e \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{l}\right) < \frac{e}{k}< \frac{e}{n}< \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the sequence $(1/n)_{n \geq 1}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\exp$ is uniformly continuous over $[0,1]$, so the sequence $(\exp(1/n))_{n \geq 1}$ is also Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, which means that $(1/n)_{n \geq 1}$ is Cauchy for your metric $d$.

Comment: I see, this is an interesting viewpoint for the problem! Still, do you happen to know how to epsilon could be chosen so that the proof can be finished in the more textbook way?